# Red neuronal genera "instruccion ilegal 'core' generado"¿ como solucionar?

Tags: python, backend, keras

trabajando en una red neuronal, a la hora de ejecutar el programa me genera el error, intenté trabajar con un backend de tensorflow,cambié la version de tensorflow, la versión de keras, trabajando dentro y fuera de un ambiente virtual y la "data" está en la misma carpeta, y antes de siquiera poder correrlo se queda unos segundos sin movimiento en la terminal y me arroja el error, trabajé con el comando "python" y también con "python3", he variado entre las versiones de keras y terminé actualizando a la versión 2.5 que tengo entendido es la última...¿como puedo solucionarlo?

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
import sys

formato = "| %-10s | %-5s | %-15s | %-10s |"
formatores = "| %-10s | %-5s | %-15s | %-2.7f |"
cadena = "_" * 53


train_data_dir = 'data/Train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/Test'
nb_train_samples = 77
nb_validation_samples = 77
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

dimension = [50, 75, 100, 125]
capa1 = [[16], [32], [64]]
capa2 = [[16, 32], [32, 16], [10, 20]]
capa3 = [[16, 32, 64], [64, 16, 32], [32, 64, 16]]

capa = [[[16], [32], [64]], [[16, 32], [32, 16], [10, 20]], [[16, 32, 64], [64, 16, 32], [32, 64, 16]]]
numcapas = 1
modo = sys.argv[1]
if modo not in ["categorical","binary"]:
    print("el argumento 2 debe estar en ", ["categorical","binary"])
    exit()

dimension = int(sys.argv[2])
img_width, img_height = dimension, dimension
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode=modo)
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode=modo)

for valorC in range(3):
    imprimirEncabezado = True

    for c in capa[valorC]:

        if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
            input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
        else:
        input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(c[0], (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        if len(c) > 1:
            model.add(Conv2D(c[1], (3, 3)))
            model.add(Activation('relu'))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        if len(c) > 2:
            model.add(Conv2D(c[2], (3, 3)))
            model.add(Activation('relu'))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(64))
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        model.add(Dense(1))
        model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='rmsprop',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

        history = model.fit(
            train_generator,
            steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
            epochs=epochs,
            verbose=0,
            validation_data=validation_generator,
            validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
        Dimension = str(dimension)
        Capas = str(valorC + 1)
        if valorC == 0 and imprimirEncabezado:
            print("\n")
            print(cadena)
            print(formato % ("Dimension", "Capa", "Filtro", "Precision"))
            print(cadena)
            imprimirEncabezado = False

        print(formatores % (
        Dimension, Capas, str(c), history.history['accuracy'][-1] * 100))
        print(cadena, "\n")
```

Comment: Y como quieres que solucionen tu problema si no sabemos cual es el error?

Comment: Ese es el detalle, no entiendo porque me arroja ese error ni como puedo hacer que lo ejecute, no sé si es problema de la máquina o error en código

Comment: pero cual es el error??? pon el mensaje de error que te da!. de lo contrario nosotros no sabremos como resolver el problema

Comment: Solo me arroja literal "Instruccion ilegal 'core' generado", asi textual, no dice nada mas, no me marca ningún warning ni error, solo esa línea